# Read mac formatted HDD in ubuntu live

Tags: live-usb, mac

I tried to read a mac HDD with corrupted OS through ubuntu live to access it and backup photos but without success.
I followed a lot of guides I found online but I'm still in trouble, I can't mount the hard disk.
Is there somebody can help me?

Comment: Please add the commands you used to try and mount it and the errors you get to the question. If there is an error we can analyze it. As it is we got nothing to go on. By the way: if it is a corrupted OS there should be tools to use from the OS itself and not from Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and and sorry for my late answer. I tried with hfsprog without success.

Now i'm at home with my own pc and i noticed the partion have not any file system (see the pic: https://postimg.cc/nsDMYRbQ).
I can mount only the recovery partition, that is pretty useless because i need to backup files.
There is something i can do to read the "unknown" partition?